# Angular navigate directly to lazy loaded module child route

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

I have an Angular module lazy loaded called example.module. In example.module I have two different components called a.component and b.component and a bunch of different sub components both a and b use.

What I would like is that when the module is lazy loaded from the router I can route directly to either one of those two components based on which route the user selected from the parent routing.

The only work around I can think of is making two entirely separate modules each of which is lazy loaded independently with the common code being in a third shared module imported by the two. That seems like a lot more templated code and files I need to produce across my entire application rather then there being some way I can signal to a lazyloaded component to load one of the routes programmatically.

```
        RouterModule.forChild(
        [
          {
            path: "",
            redirectTo: "component-a" // How do I go to A or B?
          },
          {
            path: "component-a",
            component: ComponentA
          },
          {
            path: "component-b",
            component: ComponentB
          },
        ]
```

Thanks for your assistance and knowledge on the topic!

Edit - As requested root routing.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "example",
    loadChildren: "./example.module#ExampleModule",
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
      RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Plunk - https://embed.plnkr.co/uiLFu0EBZ00F8sLH836w/

Comment: what is your `forRoot` config?

Comment: Added the main apps routing which contains forRoot which lazy loads the example module.

Comment: so when you navigate to `/example` your module is loaded and `path:''` is applied, what do you want next?

Comment: Ideally I would like two routes called example-a and example-b. When the forRoot config navigates to example-a the lazy loaded module will load a specific path instead of always loading the default path.

Comment: I want to always lazy load if one of the multiple routes are picked. Based on which route initialized the lazy load I would like to load component-a or component-b.

Comment: I don't understand. If you navigate to `/example/component-a` it will load component A, `/example/component-b` will load component B. The URL you navigate to defines which routes and consequently components will be loaded

Comment: I can get to the correct URL by adding additional paths in the forRoot component, it's that no component will show up unless in the child component you do something with the default path. If you look at Teddy Sterne example you can see he's calling 'canActivate' which then he uses to programmatically go between ComponentA and ComponentB. I'll make a plunker.

Comment: why do you need to load a module to decide where to go?

Comment: I attached a plunk. I know where I want to go, but cannot directly route to the path when two components are bundled under the same lazy loaded module. As I stated above I could split my one module into three (one shared) and lazy load each one independently but that seems like a lot more boilerplate code and files for the ability to tell the lazy loaded module which option I want to navigate to directly. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: _but cannot directly route to the path when two components are bundled under the same lazy loaded module_ - why?

Comment: When the item is lazy loaded it must run into the default route otherwise it won't load the sub component. See this plunk where I remove the empty route. Even if the path changes the component won't show. https://embed.plnkr.co/cy1jp0CMrY5Si4hzvRGg/

Comment: [it's working fine](https://plnkr.co/edit/H7lB467COfsVmoSueFlE?p=preview) if you use `routerLink="crisis-b/crisis-b"`. You seem to not understand the concepts behind routing

Comment: Ah I see I just need to link the router call from the top level and it will just figure it out itself being wrapped around the "crisis" path. I assumed I always needed to call into the lazyloaded module directly and handle further routing myself. If you can put your previous comment into an answer below I can accept. Thanks a ton for the help! Bookmarked https://blog.angularindepth.com/ to keep learning =).

Comment: posted an answer with the explanation. thanks for following the blog! :) you will find many in-depth articles there not available anywhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with lazy loaded modules you should treat them as eagerly loaded modules and the routes configuration you specify in the `.forChild(routes)` is merged into the single application wide configuration.

So in your particular case you define in the `forRoot`:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-a', loadChildren: 'app/crisis/crisis.module#CrisisModule' },
  { path: 'crisis-b', loadChildren: 'app/crisis/crisis.module#CrisisModule' }
];
```

and in the `.forChild()`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-a',    component: CrisisListComponentA },
  { path: 'crisis-b',    component: CrisisListComponentB },
];
```

So once merged you will have the following configuration:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'crisis-a', 
    children: [
        { path: 'crisis-a',    component: CrisisListComponentA },
        { path: 'crisis-b',    component: CrisisListComponentB }
    ]
  { 
    path: 'crisis-b', 
    children: [
        { path: 'crisis-a',    component: CrisisListComponentA },
        { path: 'crisis-b',    component: CrisisListComponentB }
    ]
  }
];
```

Hence if you want to navigate to `CrisisListComponentB` with `/crisis-b` you have to specify full URL

```
/crisis-b/crisis-b
```

Comment: just came across to the answer... Answer helped me also out! A small improvement though: routes: [ { path: 'crisis-a' : component: CrisisListComponentA} ] would still work and removes the duplication. So without the default paths in the child crisis router.

Comment: but it's not very user friendly to have all these double urls

Answer (score 1):

I would make a `canActivate` guard to route them appropriately once the module is resolved.

Update the routes to be:

```js
RouterModule.forChild(
[
  {
    path: "",
    canActivate: [RootRouteGuard]
  },
  {
    path: "component-a",
    component: ComponentA
  },
  {
    path: "component-b",
    component: ComponentB
  },
]
```

And then the guard would look something like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class RootRouteGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    if (/* Logic */) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('component-a');
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('component-b');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it would work. I'll test it out and accept as answer unless a better alternative comes up. Thanks!

Comment: This might be possible to do, when I tried it basically borks my app into an infinite loop because i'm calling navigateByUrl into the same module which then calls RootRouteGuard again. The actual answer was looking for was calling the route nested into the parent. I over complicated the problem. Thanks for your insight!